# group theory proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G=\langle t \rangle$ be a cyclic group with $\text{ord}(t)=n$.
I want to show that for all $d|n$ it holds that 
$$\left\lbrace s \in G ;\text{ord}(s)=d \right\rbrace=\left\lbrace t^{\frac{n}{d}k} ; 1 \leq k \leq d, 1=\text{gcd}(k,d) \right\rbrace $$

Comment: I think when I use that for all $d|n$ 
$$|\left\lbrace s \in G ;\text{ord}(s)=d\right\rbrace|=\varphi(d)$$ I can already see that
$$|\left\lbrace s \in G ;\text{ord}(s)=d\right\rbrace|=\varphi(d)=\left|\left\lbrace t^{\frac{n}{d}k} ; 1 \leq k \leq d, 1=\text{gcd}(k,d) \right\rbrace\right|$$

Comment: If you can see that equality, than all that remains is to show that every element of the set on the right has order exactly $d$ --- that is, that its $d^{\mathrm{th}}$ power is the identity and that no lower power is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $m<d$ and $(t^{\frac{n}{d}k})^m=1$ it follows that
$$t^{\frac{n}{d}km}=1 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{nkm}{d} = nz, z \in \mathbb{Z}\Longleftrightarrow  \frac{km}{d} = z$$ 
which is a contradiction because $m<d$ and $\text{gcd}(k,d)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be cylic group with order $n$ with $G=\{e,t,t^2,...,t^{n-1}\}$.

**fact$1$:** $O(t^i)=\dfrac{n}{gcd(n,i)}$ where $O(t^i)$ represents the order of $t^i$.

By fact$1$ all generators of $G$ in the form $t^i$ where $(i,n)=1$.

**fact$2$:** For all $d|n$, Cyclic group has ecaxtly one subgroup of order $d$.

Now let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ with order $d$. We know that it is also cyclic and since $a=t^{\frac n d}$ has order $d$ then $H=<a>$ since $H$ is uniqe .

By fact$1$, All generators of $H$ are of the form $a^i$ where $(i,d)=1$ we are done.

Comment: I'm sorry but both facts are not really well known to me - I have not proven them yet. Do you know another way to show it? I think it can't be really hard if I use that $$|\left\lbrace s \in G ;\text{ord}(s)=d\right\rbrace|=\varphi(d)=\left|\left\lbrace t^{\frac{n}{d}k} ; 1 \leq k \leq d, 1=\text{gcd}(k,d) \right\rbrace\right|$$ I thought I just have to show that $(t^{\frac{n}{d}k})^m \neq 1$ for $m<n$. Is this right and how can I do this?

Comment: @chris: Only thing which you need to see that, for any element $g$ you want to find integer such that $g^k$ has same order. And Such $k$ 's are exactly the ones which are relativly prime to $o(g)$. (you already know that $t^{n\over d}$ has order $d$.)